# php cli udp server socket

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp, php

Below code is my **PHP CLi TCP server socket**  , but I try to make a **TCP & UDP socket server** or just **udp server** , but I don't know how can make it

***MyCodes:***

```
// PHP SOCKET SERVER
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
// Configuration variables
$host = "192.168.0.1";
$port = 5009;
$max = 20;

// MySQL Database Conf
$db_host ='localhost';
$db_user ='root';
$db_pass ='5222348';
$db_database ='gps';

mysql_connect("$db_host", "$db_user", "$db_pass")or die("################# Can't connet to mysql server");
mysql_select_db("$db_database")or die("################# Can't connet to database");

// --------------------------------
$client = array();

// No timeouts, flush content immediatly
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush();

// Server functions
function rLog($msg){
             $msg = "\n[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."]:".$msg;
             echo($msg);

}
// Create socket
// $sock = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0) or die("[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."] Could not create socket\n");  UDP communication
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0) or die("[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."] Could not create socket\n");
// Bind to socket
socket_bind($sock,$host,$port) or die("[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."] Could not bind to socket\n");
// Start listening
socket_listen($sock) or die("[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."] Could not set up socket listener\n");

rLog("
Server started at ".$host.":".$port."\nrev:23-7-11:13");
// Server loop
while(true){
             socket_set_block($sock);
             // Setup clients listen socket for reading
             $read[0] = $sock;
             for($i = 0;$i<$max;$i++){
                          if($client[$i]['sock'] != null)
                                       $read[$i+1] = $client[$i]['sock'];
             }
             // Set up a blocking call to socket_select()
             $ready = socket_select($read,$write = NULL, $except = NULL, $tv_sec = NULL);
             // If a new connection is being made add it to the clients array
             if(in_array($sock,$read)){
                          for($i = 0;$i<$max;$i++){
                                       if($client[$i]['sock']==null){
                                                    if(($client[$i]['sock'] = socket_accept($sock))<0){
                                                                 rLog("socket_accept() failed: ".socket_strerror($client[$i]['sock']));
                                                    }else{
                                                                 socket_getpeername($client[$i]['sock'], $address, $port);
                                                                 rLog("Client #".$i." connected from : ".$address.":".$port."");
                                                    }
                                                    break;
                                       }elseif($i == $max - 1){
                                                    rLog("Too many clients");
                                       }
                          }
                          if(--$ready <= 0)
                          continue;
             }
             for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
                          if(in_array($client[$i]['sock'],$read)){
                                       $input = socket_read($client[$i]['sock'],1024);
                                       if($input==null){
                                                    unset($client[$i]);
                                       }
                                       $n = trim($input);
                                       $com = split(" ",$n);
                                       if($n=="EXIT"){
                                                    if($client[$i]['sock']!=null){
                                                                 // Disconnect requested
                                                                 socket_close($client[$i]['sock']);
                                                                 unset($client[$i]['sock']);
                                                                 rLog("Disconnected(2) client #".$i);
                                                                 for($p=0;$p<count($client);$p++){
                                                                              socket_write($client[$p]['sock'],"DISC ".$i.chr(0));
                                                                 }
                                                                 if($i == $adm){
                                                                              $adm = -1;
                                                                 }
                                                    }
                                       }elseif($n=="TERM"){
                                                    // Server termination requested
                                                    socket_close($sock);
                                                    rLog("Terminated server (requested by client #".$i.")");
                                                    exit();
                                       }elseif($input){


                                                    // ----------------------------------------- //
                                                    // $handle = fopen('inbox.txt', 'a+');
                                                    // fwrite($handle, 
                                                        // $input."\n".
                                                        // "------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                                                    // ########################################################################################### //
                                                    // $input  = "$POS,115316,160137.000,A,2719.9343,N,05310.5553,E,0.00,,180712,,,A/00000,00000/0,0,0,0/794"; // Sample Data
                                                    $input_first = explode(",", $input);

                                                    $frstvalue=$input_first[0];  // $POS            -   Command

                                                    echo $input;
                                                            $handle = fopen('force.log', 'a+');
                                                            fwrite($handle, 
                                                                "Time:[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."] , from : ".$address.":".$port."\ninput: ".$input."\n".
                                                                "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                                                    ###########################
                                       }
                          }else{

                                       //}
                          }
             }
}
// Close the master sockets
socket_close($sock);
```

above codes is work perfectly on TCP connections , but can't give UDP requests .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP, being a datagram transport, is a bit different from TCP:

- Remove call to `socket_listen`, it's not applicable to UDP.
- Remove call to `socket_accept`, same.
- Use [`socket_recvfrom`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recvfrom.php) to receive datagrams on `$sock` in a loop.

That is to say that your original `$sock` is the data socket, i.e. you only need one here.

PHP also offers simplified [`stream_socket_server`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-server.php) interface that you can use with a `"udp://..."` URL.

Comment: Thanks , I do it , but think I have a problem on set this changes , can set above changes on first post original codes ? ;)

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. If you want me to edit your code - no, I'm not doing that.

Comment: I Use it but give error :-? , Send inputs from udp is not echo on server .